# ReferenceError: The plugin "react.displayName" collides with another of the same name

Tags: reactjs, yeoman, redux

I've used "redux generator" from yeoman and installed things.

When I run "npm start", the project loads but displays this log

ERROR in ./js/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: The plugin "react.displayName" collides with another of the same name
    at PluginManager.validate (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:159:13)
    at PluginManager.add (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:213:10)
    at File.buildTransformers (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:237:21)
    at new File (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:10)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
    at transpile (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:12:22)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/acejordan/Projects/redcli/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:71:12)
 @ multi main

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You may try contact to whoever maintains that template.

Answer (score 0):

See here => https://github.com/banderson/generator-redux/issues/35 (I'm hoping this is where the fix will come).